# Monaca Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, monaca

I have the following code and the simple js shown is not working. How do I make js work in monaca?

Here is the code for what I am doing.

I have added jQuery (Monaca Version) Version: 2.0.3 from the config screen, by the way.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
  <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script>
    //this starts the count down. 
    //time should be in seconds
    function countDown(time){
        $("#countDown").txt(time);
        var timeout=setTimeout(function(){
            time--;
            $("#countDown").txt(time);
            if(time==0) clearTimeout(timeout);
        }, 1000);
    }

    ons.ready(function() {
        countDown(10);
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="countDown"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you've made a typo in assigning the value of the `time` variable to the `<div>` element. It is not `$("#countDown").txt(time);`, it's `$("#countDown").text(time);`.

Also, judging from the name of your function - `countdown` I'm guessing you are trying to create a counter appearing on the screen. In that case you should not be using the `setTimeout(function, period)` function, as this is used to call the function passed as its argument, only once after the period (passed as the second argument) passes. Therefore, you should use the `setInterval(function(),period)` function, which calls the function every time the period passes. Accordingly you should use `clearInterval()` instead of `clearTimeout()`.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<script>
    //this starts the count down. 
    //time should be in seconds
    function countDown(time){
        $("#countDown").text(time);
        var timeout=setInterval(function(){
            time--;
            $("#countDown").text(time);
            if(time==0) clearInterval(timeout);
        }, 1000);
    }

    ons.ready(function() {
        countDown(10);
    });
</script>
```